# Convert Dropdownlist item's value to int

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, razor, drop-down-menu

I need the value of SelectListItem to be int.

So I pull it of the database, convert it to string in the process and store to listitem's value.

```
public class BookAdd
{
public BookAdd()
{
public Book Book { get; set; }
DataModelContainer db = new DataModelContainer();
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.PublisherSet
               .Select(i => new SelectListItem
               {
                 Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)i.Id), 
                 Text = i.Name
               });
    }
}
```

I then need to store the value again as int to Book.PublisherId when selected from dropdownlist. I know the code below is not complete, I figured I need somehow convert the selected item's value to int, how do I do it?

```
@model Bookshops.Models.BookAdd
...
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Book.PublisherId, Model.items);
```

And finaly controler:

```
    public ActionResult Create2()
    {
        var bookAdd = new BookAdd();
        ViewBag.Publisher = bookAdd.items;
        return View(bookAdd);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Book/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create2(BookAdd book)
    {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Book book2 = new Book();
                book2.Id = book.Book.Id;
                book2.AuthorId = book.Book.AuthorId;
                book2.Isbn = book.Book.Isbn;
                book2.Id = int.Parse(book.Book.PubId);
                book2.Title = book.Book.Title;
                book2.YearPublished = book.Book.YearPublished;

                db.BookSet.Add(book2);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

I'm using MVC 3, EF 4.

Comment: How are you accepting that into the controller? It's possible that model binding will accept that as an integer for you if the naming is appropriate. Are you submitting an entire form? You could probably do something like @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Book.PublisherId), Model.Items); But it would only add another point of failure to your app.

Comment: i have added my controller code.. I will try the conversion you suggested and let you knoe the results

Comment: MVC Model binding should handle the conversion for you if you have a the appropriate property on the BookAdd model. Have you tried it without any explicit conversions? If you did, what was the result?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of building a `SelectListItem`, I built something like this:

```
public struct BookItem
{
   int id;
   string name;
}
```

Then add the following item to the model and select data into it

```
IEnumerable<BookItem> bookList {get; set;}
```

Fianally

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Book.PublicherId, new SelectList(Model.bookList, "id", "name"))
```

Answer (score 0):

When the selected Item of the DropDownList will get posted back convert it to int from string like this Convert.ToInt32(DropDownSelectedItem) or with Int32.TryParse(value, out number)

Comment: could you elaborate more? where exactly do I make the conversion?

Comment: Example : When you post data back to an controller/action, you can do the conversion their

Comment: i hoped i could do some linq magic on the model => model.Book.PublisherId

Answer (score 0):

to start you can simplify the mapping code to

```
db
    .PublisherSet
    .Select(x=> new SelectListItem{Value = x.Id.ToString(), Text = x.Name})
    .ToArray();
```

In the view you can then do

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Book.PublisherId, Model.items);
```

and it will properly render a select element with the options and the appropriate publisher selected.

You can then use the model binding conventions to pass this back to the controller action when the user clicks the submit button.

In the end, it's all text. that's the nature of the web. we have a lot of tricks, converters and binders to turn string dictionaries into rich view models, but ultimately it's just strings.

Comment: your mapping code just causes: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: I'm not woorried about the Linq expression, it does what it does right.  I need the second snipped to convert the value to int.

Comment: model binding should do this for you automatically.