# Convert Dropdown list value to int before sending to model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have a form, and a dropdown list in that form whose item's value is of type string. I need to store the selected list item's value to Book.PublisherId, which is int. How do i edit code below, which assumes PublisherId is string?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Book.PublisherId, Model.items);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Dropdownlist item's value to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231997/convert-dropdownlist-items-value-to-int)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change anything. If values in Model.items can be converted to int, you'll get a correct int value in the Book.PublisherId property after submitting the form.